# What is difference between float-extended-exponent and float in java

Tags: java, floating-point, jvm, jls

The section [2.8.2. Floating-Point Modes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.8.2) of the Java Virtual Machine Specification describes about float-extended-exponent and float value sets.

1. What does it mean?
2. In what way does it affect the floating point representation in the program ?
3. What are floating-point modes?
4. Which representation is supported by most implementations ?

Answer (score 3):

See section 2.3.2, and Table 2.1, of the page you linked.  The different "value sets" can represent different ranges of numbers.

> The finite nonzero values of any floating-point value set can all be expressed in the form s ⋅ m ⋅ 2^{e − N + 1}, where s is +1 or −1, m is a positive integer less than 2N, and e is an integer between Emin = −(2^{K−1}−2) and Emax = 2^{K−1}−1, inclusive, and where N and K are parameters that depend on the value set.

The "extended-exponent" value sets have larger K values than the non-extended-exponent.  That means they can handle numbers that are larger in magnitude than the non-extended-exponent value sets.

Answer (score 3):

- The *float value set* is the set of values that can be represented using the [single floating-point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) defined in the IEEE 754 standard.
- The *float-extended-exponent value set* is a set of values with the same precision (24 bits), but larger exponent range.

There are 2 *Floating-Point Modes*:

- "FP-strict": use exact IEEE 754 arithmetic: in other words, all `float`s (and intermediate calculations) are computed using values in the *float value set*
- "not FP-strict": allow extended range numbers, i.e. `float`s (and intermediate value computations) can take values in the *float-extended-exponent value set*.

The mode is determined by (a) the computer architecture, and (b) the `strictfp` flag.

For more details, see [`strictfp`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictfp) wikipedia page, which provides some background.